# Create partial php.ini files

Tags: php

I want to two split php.ini into two files so that I can move important entries to a new file. I think it is a .ini file so, any rule for creating partial .ini files will also apply to it. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you would not split a php.ini file unless it was a direct copy, you would make a script that would generate a new php.ini in the location of your choice with the rules that you require.

Your best bet would be to do a little ground work on how to generate text based files in Windows or Linux whichever is your hosting environment and then when you have some code your stuck on, post it on [Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/).